# keyframe animation-delay for each list item?

Tags: jquery, animation, css-animations

Happy Eastern,

I am using Javascript and Jake Weary to fill and display an unordered List on my Page.
First a for loop to push li's with content into an array, then:

```
var join = array.join("");
$("#list_view").html("<ul>"+join+"</ul>");
$("#list_view").show();
$("#list_view > ul > li").addClass("list_flip");
```

The list_view div is initially hidden and the list_flip class contains a CSS Keyframe Animation.

```
.list_flip {
animation: flip 1s linear;
}
@keyframes flip {
0% {transform: rotateX(180deg);}
100% {transform: rotateX(0deg);}
}
```

This works quite well, but I would like to have a small delay between each li "flipping in" rather than all of them at once.

The list length may be different each time, so i cant address the list items directly in CSS.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

youd want to loop through all the list items and use their index as a variable to their delay:

```
$("#list_view > ul > li").each(function(idx,value){
    $(this).addClass("list_flip");
    $(this).css({
        "-webkit-animation-delay":idx+"s",
        "-moz-animation-delay":idx+"s",
        "-ms-animation-delay":idx+"s",
        "-o-animation-delay":idx+"s",
        "animation-delay":idx+"s"
    });
});
```

here is an example : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/TV2j3/)